# Better comments VS Code extension, only works with multiple line comments?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've installed this [Better Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments&ssr=false#review-details) extension for Visual Studio Code. It only seems to work on Typescript for multiple-line comments, not single line. I've had a look at the docs but couldn't find any settings or anything to make it single-line.

Is this only for multi-line use, or has someone out there achieved coloured single lines comments too?

Comment: Works for me out of the box with single line comments, e.g. // TODO <- will be orange. Not sure how I can help as there are hardly any extension settings for it; ironically there is an option for Multiline Comments but not single line. Perhaps you have a VSCode theme which is conflicting or another plugin also responsible for colouring comments?

Comment: https://github.com/aaron-bond/better-comments/issues is the right place for such questions, not here.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, this [Auto Comment Blocks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kevinkyang.auto-comment-blocks) extension conflicts with the better comments, it works fine now